# Mark code to not run at design-time

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

When using the new Xamarin.iOS designer, it will automatically create your controllers, views, etc. so your C# code runs and actually renders on the design surface (instead of having to wait until runtime).

So if you have a controller, it's constructor and `ViewDidLoad` will be called.

So let's say I have a controller like so:

```
class MyController
{
    readonly ISomeService service;

    public MyController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        service = MyIoCContainer.Get<ISomeService>();
    }
}
```

Obviously at design-time, the IoC container will be completely empty and throw an exception.

Is there a way to solve this issue with the Xamarin.iOS designer? Perhaps `#if !DESIGN_TIME` or something to that nature? Or is there a way I could make my IoC container return a mock instance of all objects at design-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current recommended way to do this is to have your class implement the IComponent interface. See [this doc](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/#Design_Mode) for more information. So your MyController class might look something like this:

```
[Register ("MyController")]
class MyController : UIViewController, IComponent
{
    #region IComponent implementation

    public ISite Site { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    #endregion

    readonly ISomeService service;

    public MyController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib ()
    {
        if (Site == null || !Site.DesignMode)
            service = MyIoCContainer.Get<ISomeService>();
    }
}
```

Note that Site will always be `null` in the constructor. The preferred place for initialization from a storyboard is the `AwakeFromNib` method. I updated the code sample to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question over the weekend; I wanted a quick and easy way to prevent making an API call from ViewDidLoad when looking at a view controller in the designer.

Here's a quick and easy check I created for dealing with it. (Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25835680/841832)

The Studio Storyboard designer does not call the AppDelegate events, so you can utilize that to create a check.

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public partial class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public static bool IsInDesignerView = true;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        IsInDesignerView = false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
public class MyController: UIViewController
{
    readonly ISomeService service;

    public MyController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        service = AppDelegate.IsInDesignerView ?
            new Moq<ISomeService>() :
            MyIoCContainer.Get<ISomeService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your way works too, but I think @chkn's method is the preferred. They followed the same pattern from older designers, such as WinForms. Yours is probably simpler, though.