# Storyboard message: Custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I have an IOS app-project developed using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013 which I haven't opened for about a year. Now I have to make some changes to the app and after some problems compiling the project I installed all available updates for Xamarin and Visual Studio 2013, but that only made things worse so I decided to install Visual Studio 2015 and update the Mac and Xcode to the latest version.

Installing VS2015 seemed to solve all my previous problems and I can now compile the project and run it fine (in VS2015), but when I open the storyboard (there is only one in the project) I get a yellow warning bar at the top that says *Custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected*.

[image: Storyboard warning msg]

I have no idea why this message appears since I only use standard components (or maybe "components" means something else than those in the Toolbox?). Does anyone know what the reason for this message is, how can I troubleshoot and get rid of it?

I should add that I'm not an experienced IOS developer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825424/in-xamarin-ios-designer-how-can-i-prevent-code-from-being-run-in-viewdidload ?

Comment: You could file a bug with your logs attached: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/.

Comment: @matt I don't think this is a duplicate, the iOS Storyboards in Xamarin read an XML sheet essentially.